# How to change the number of columns and rows for my DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I have the following Model Class validation:

```
public class Group_validation
    {

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
       [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
       [StringLength(200)]
       public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

But currently I have the following questions:

1. How I can define the number of columns and rows for the `DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]`
2. the `StringLenght` data annotation client side validation will stop working when I add the `DataType(DataType.MultilineText)].` so in my case the StringLenght will work as a the client side validation for the Name field,  but will only work only as a  server side validation for the Description field.

Can anyone advice how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You could make it with the help of HTML Helper class

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new {cols = 50, rows = 5})
```

Comment: I tried this  @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "textArea"})
.textArea {
    height:500em; width:500em;
} .but it did not work.

Comment: `cols` and `rows` aren't reserved words in that context, so you don't need the verbatim string literal qualifier. :)

Answer (score -1):

try

`@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Descricao, 5, 50, null)`

in View Page